# How to get custom Devise User fields into other controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple app that allows users to submit requests. It uses Devise to allow them to register and authenticate. I want to use a custom Devise User field ('first_name') in my 'requests_controller.rb'

I can get values from the request no problem with code like:

```
@request = current_user.requests.new(request_params)
@userid = "#{@request[:user_id]}"
puts "@userid: #{@userid}"
```

This will output the Devise User :user_id (an integer).

But code like this returns nil:

```
@name = "#{@request[:first_name]}"
puts "@name: #{@name}"
```

Here is how I setup my app and added custom fields:

I created my User model with

```
rails generate devise User
```

And then modified the migration to look like this:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,       :unique => true
  end
end
```

And my model to look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

I created a foreign key for my users with:

```
rails generate migration AddUserIdToRequest user_id:integer
```

And finally associated the two models in a one to many relationship with:

```
has_many :requests
```

In app/models/user.rb

And

```
belongs_to :user
```

In app/models/request.rb

I have the following code that adds custom fields to the Devise User (credit to Jaco Pretorius):

Migration

```
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

Views

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

So far so good. This code adds two new fields to the Devise User and the new registration page. Now to my question. How do I access these new fields in another controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `devise_parameter_sanitizer` in your `application_controller` like

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

and set a before action to check whether its a devise controller using

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```